# MarkLogic mlcp import not working - Unable to connect to localhost to query destination information

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am running mlcp import within a docker container .
I have first installed the MarkLogic application and mlcp in a centOS7 machine and on top of the installed application I am trying to import a xml file using mlcp command.

After the installation I can see that the MarkLogic is up and running at port8001.
However, when I tried to execute mlcp it returns me this error -

```
22/11/07 14:13:33 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.2.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
22/11/07 14:13:33 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Job name: local_879652095_1
22/11/07 14:13:33 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
22/11/07 14:13:37 ERROR contentpump.ThreadManager: Query evaluation request rejected (404, Not Found).
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerResponseException: Query evaluation request rejected (404, Not Found).
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.NotFoundCodeHandler.handleResponse(NotFoundCodeHandler.java:40) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.EvalRequestController.serverDialog(EvalRequestController.java:109) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:92) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:495) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:490) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ThreadManager.queryServerMaxThreads(ThreadManager.java:143) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(MarkLogicOutputFormat.java:95) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:126) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:356) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:255) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
22/11/07 14:13:37 WARN mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat: Unable to connect to localhost to query destination information
22/11/07 14:13:37 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error checking output specification:
22/11/07 14:13:37 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Unable to query destination information, no usable hostname found
```

In the MarkLogic admin console the hostname is localhost.
The bind port is 7999.
Foreign port is 7998.

**Update: This is sorted now. I was using wrong port. The correct port will be 8000.**

Comment: The 7xxx ports are irrelevant. Please post as much of your MLCP config file or command as you can make public

Comment: exec /opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/bin/mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8001 -username admin -password admin@123 -input_file_path /opt/mlcp-10.0.9-bin/mlcp-10.0.9/bin/MyFirstTDE.xml -database Documents -input_file_type documents -document_type xml

Comment: @DavidEnnis__17llamas__ I am executing this mlcp command from a bash file

Comment: Port 8001 is the default ML admin interface port. Are you sure that is the XCC port you want to use in your mlcp shell script?.

I could run mlcp from the docker container without issue. Pls make sure that XCC port is open in your docker container.

Comment: @XCELERENT-Iwanttodance How to check for the XCC port please ?

Comment: I have already published the ports while running the docker - docker build -t wrapperscript . ;; docker run -it --name=wrapperscript --hostname=localhost -p 8000-8002:8000-8002 wrapperscript:latest